# Integer Factorisation

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers, factoring

If I have a set of numbers  of the form $\{ {kp+r}:k\geq0\}$  with p a prime or product of primes k large in  $\in Z^+$ and r fixed, is it computationally feasible to find a factorisation for any one of these numbers, supposing p is very large > 1000 bits.

For context, I am thinking whether this variant of the integer factorisation problem is acceptable.

Cheers.

Comment: What is r? Is it different for all numbers? How large is it? How large is k? Are k and r picked uniformly at random?

Answer (score -1):

The solution to this problem is extended euclid which is a polynomial algorithm.

Comment: While this may be enough for you to understand how the solution works, it may not be enough detail for everybody to understand how the solution work, so please [edit](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/55615/edit) your answer.